# List Duplicates Between Two Files and Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008 and imported two files into a table. The first file (2048) has 6,721 rows, the second file has (2209) 4,707 rows and the columns are: `Billed, FirstName, LastName, FileID`. Table is called `Claims`.

Need query to list each `FileId` (2209 and 2048) showing the duplicates in each file and delete the duplicates from one of them.

Ran this query:

```
SELECT firstname
, lastname
, duplicatecount = COUNT(1)
FROM Claims
WHERE fileid IN (2209, 2048)
GROUP BY
firstname
, lastname
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

Comment: Is there the possibility of having duplicates within an individual file, or is it just the case that you want to find records in file 2209 where the record is also in file 2048?

Comment: You want to find duplicates in each file? Between file? and delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are duplicates.  So start with your query:

```
with todelete as (<your query here>)
delete from Claims
    from todelete
    where todelete.firstname = claims.firstname and
          todelete.lastname = claims.lastname and
          fileid = 2209
```

You want to delete the *duplicate* value, not all of them, so you need to specify which one to remove.  I arbitrarily chose 2209.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the duplicates in each file,

```
SELECT firstname , lastname , count(*) as duplicatecount 
FROM Claims WHERE fileid IN (2209, 2048) 
GROUP BY firstname , lastname HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY 1,2 DESC
```

Try this

Comment: Looks very much like the query in the original post.

Comment: yeah @AndriyM, but OP didnt say what he is getting and he mentioned that he want to know the duplicates in each file. Then the deleting part I dont understand. U have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
WITH counted_and_marked AS (
  SELECT
    *
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY firstname, lastname ORDER BY fileid)
  FROM Claims
  WHERE fileid IN (2209, 2048)
)
DELETE FROM marked_and_counted
WHERE rnk > 1
;
```

The `marked_and_counted` common table expression simply retrieves all the rows from `Claims`, independently ranking duplicates of every `(firstname, lastname)` in the order of `fileid`. The DELETE statement then deletes only rows with rankings greater than 1.

You can see that DELETE targets the CTE directly, which is allowed in this case, because the CTE references only one table.

This query will work for an arbitrary number of files. It will remove duplicates across all of them, leaving only one entry per `(firstname, lastname)`.